# How to make a function be an alias to a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-1.0

I am trying to rename a few of my cmdlets and want to do it without breaking existing scripts. I want to do it without using Set-Alias/New-Alias because I do not want the Aliases to show up when we do Get-Command from the powershell prompt and I thought it might be possible to use exported functions to achieve the same thing that aliasing cmdlets would do.

Here is an example of what I want to do

```
Old cmdlet - Add-Foo
Renamed cmdlet - Add-FooBar
Expectation - Scripts using Add-Foo should continue to work the same way as it used to
```

I am thinking of introducing the following function

```
function Add-Foo()
{
   # Delegate parameter inputs to cmdlet Add-FooBar
}
```

I have a simple version of it but I am not sure if it would work in more complex cases.

```
function Add-Foo()
{
   $cmd = "Add-FooBar"
   if ($arguments.Length -eq 0){
     Invoke-Expression $cmd;
   }
   else{
     # Concatentate cmdlet and arguments into an expression
     $expr = "$($cmd)  $($args)";
     Write-Debug $expr;
     Invoke-Expression $expr;
   }
}
```

I am not sure if my function is going to be 100% compatible with existing usages. Can the function Add-Foo be made such that it behaves well with parameter attributes (pipeline binding) and any other possible usages? Essentially I want the function to take the arguments as is and pass it to the underlying renamed cmdlet.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Functions are going to show up when you do a Get-Command, just like Aliases.

Comment: True. But there is another problem - Aliases interfere with the help tooling that we have for cmdlets - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/05/08/cmdlet-help-editor-tool.aspx

Comment: Proxy commands are the way to go if you care about things like pipeline parameter binding.  Splatting @args is another possibility (starting in V3), but that won't support pipelining like a proxy command would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell has a built-in feature for this: Proxy commands.

The [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand] class has several static methods to help out with this. Below is a template you can use to generate a proxy command and add a condition choosing whether or not to call the original command.

```
function New-ProxyCommand($command)
{
    $cmd = Get-Command $command
    $blocks = @{
        CmdletBinding = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetCmdletBindingAttribute($cmd)
        Params        = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetParamBlock($cmd)
        Begin         = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetBegin($cmd)
        Process       = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetProcess($cmd)
        End           = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetEnd($cmd)
    }

    # Indent
    filter Indent($indent='    ') { $_ | foreach { ($_ -split "`r`n" | foreach { "${indent}$_" }) -join "`r`n" } }
    [array]$blocks.Keys | foreach { $blocks[$_] = $blocks[$_] | Indent }

    @"
function $command
{
$($blocks.CmdletBinding)
    param
    ($($blocks.Params)
    )

    begin
    {
        `$Reroute = `$false  ### Put your conditions here ###

        if (`$Reroute) { return }
    $($blocks.Begin)}

    process
    {
        if (`$Reroute) { return }
    $($blocks.Process)}

    end
    {
        if (`$Reroute) { return }
    $($blocks.End)}
}
"@
}
```

Example:

```
PS> New-ProxyCommand Get-Item

function Get-Item
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Path', SupportsTransactions=$true, HelpUri='http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113319')]
    param
    (    
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Path', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]
        ${Path},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralPath', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [string[]]
        ${LiteralPath},

        [string]
        ${Filter},

        [string[]]
        ${Include},

        [string[]]
        ${Exclude},

        [switch]
        ${Force},

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [pscredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]
        ${Credential}
    )

    begin
    {
        $Reroute = $false  ### Put your conditions here ###

        if ($Reroute) { return }

        try {
            $outBuffer = $null
            if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
            {
                $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
            }
            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Get-Item', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
            $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    process
    {
        if ($Reroute) { return }

        try {
            $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    end
    {
        if ($Reroute) { return }

        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wonderful! Thank you.  There was one minor issue with the generated function that is kept throwing an error at the line $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Get-Item', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet). I replaced it with Get-Command Get-Item and it was fine. I assume it was a bug with the version of Powershell that I have.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Strange about the error. I did a quick test in v2 and v3, but nothing too thorough.

Just a headsup, if you do replace '$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand' with Get-Command, it is a good idea to fully qualify it as 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Get-Command'. This way you can be sure you're not calling a proxied version of it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a private function:

```
function Private:Add-Foo
{
  Add-Foobar $args
}
```

Add-Foo will only call this function in the current scope.  The function will not be visible within any child scope (like a called script), and they will use the Add-Foo cmdlet instead.

Comment: This doesn't work with named arguments.  In V3, you could write: Add-Foobar @args (splat the argument array) and that will work with named arguments.

Comment: If you want full named parameter support you'll need to duplicate the proxied cmdlet's parameter set in your function.  Splatting will pass named parameters, and you can emulate that behavior in a v1/v2 function, but you'll still lose other features like tab completion and validation.